# more efficient jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this following piece of code works, but it sort of makes the browser quirk just a bit.  Nothing major.  I'm wondering if there would be a way to make this more efficient?  Can I use caching or somehow populate one select and then just copy it to the other 5.  (there are 6 drop downs with a class of 'mask' on the page.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('.mask').each(function () {
  $(this).append($('<option/>').val("").text(""));
    for (var i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
      $(this).append($('<option/>').val(i).text(i));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create the nodes once then clone them, like this:

```
var temp = $('<select/>');
$('<option/>').val("").text("").appendTo(temp);
for (var i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
  $('<option/>').val(i).text(i).appendTo(temp);
}
temp.children().clone().appendTo('.mask');
```

Instead of doing a lot of individual appends to the DOM (which is very costly) this batches all the elements up in a document fragment then clones them, appending in batches (one batch per select).

Comment: Can someone elaborate why this is preferred even though its not as fast as the solution above?

Comment: @Kyle - it's safer to use DOM creation of your nodes, for example a quote in the value, etc (though safe in *this particular case*) will cause issues, invalid HTML and unpredictable rendering.  To be safe, stick with DOM creation methods, not HTML via string generation.

Answer (score 6):

It's much faster (around 3-10 times, as tested [here](http://jsperf.com/appending-options-jquery)) to build up the HTML yourself in a single string:

```
var html = "<option value=''></option>";
for (var i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
   html += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}
$(".mask").append(html);
```

See performance test comparing the current options in this thread: http://jsperf.com/appending-options-jquery

Comment: This is obviously the faster the solution, but it doesn't seem to be what everyone prefers to use?  Can someone elaborate why this is not as good as a solution below?